# Login doesn't work in dev with Symfony

Tags: symfony, authentication, server

I'm trying to create a login page for the admin of my portfolio. I readed the documentation on security and did the "1) Initial security.yml Setup (Authentication)" part (http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#security-encoding-password). I encrypted my password with bcrypt.

When I'm on my localhost, it works perfectly fine, but when I try using app.php instead of app_dev.php, it doesn't work. On my server, neither works (I made the app_dev.php file work on server just to test this). AN other thing is that my log file doesn't tell my anything when it doesn't work.

When it doesn't work, it pop up a form asking my my username and password and as soon as I entered them, it just diseppear, then reapper asking me again my username and password.

Why is it just working dev on my localhost?

Comment: If you want some help from SO community you need to update your question with all the info related to the problem. Read [How to ask a good question on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before updating.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I readed what you ask me to and I did change a few things, but not much since I really don't see the problem with my question, since I wrote absolutly everything I know about my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After working on some other things, the login work fine, so I guess I just made a typo somewhere... Basically, if you have the dame problem as I had, just start the connexion from scratch and closely follow the instruction on Symfony web site:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html